# Selenium webdriver : Ajax live search not triggered while sending keys in text field

Tags: java, selenium

While sending keys through text field (using `SendKeys(" ")`) the javascript is not catching the keypress event, thus the ajax live search fails to trigger. When done manually it working well.

The problem comes only when executing through selenium webdriver code.

Any particular or best practice to press a key so that ajax live search works during execution?

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML code snippet and the code that you've worked upon so far ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Use typeKeys

```
<tr>
    <td>typeKeys </td>
    <td>id=Location</td>
    <td>\40</td>
</tr>
```

#### [Click here for reference for codes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html)

#### Wait for element present

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=ui-active-menuitem</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Javascript Executor` can be used to fire events manually; in this case following can be used here `yourEvent` is the event which is fired when some value is entered:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("some_id"));

element.sendKeys("your input");
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].fireEvent('yourEvent');", element);
```